# Should std.algorithm.find demand a reference to range elements?

Tags: d, phobos

I have been working on a class-based finite random access range. When performing a few tests on it:

```
auto myRange = /* construct my range */
static assert (isRandomAccessRange!(typeof(myRange))); // 
static assert (!isInfinite!(typeof(myRange)));         // both pass 
auto preamble = myRange[0..128];
assert( all!"a == 0"(preamble)); // check for all zeros
```

I got this compilation error in GDC 4.9.2, regarding the last line in the snippet above: "algorithm.d|4838|error: foreach: cannot make e ref"

The error points to this piece of code in `std.algorithm.find` (the find_if variant, taking a range and a predicate), which indeed takes a reference to each element with `foreach`:

```
InputRange find(alias pred, InputRange)(InputRange haystack)
if (isInputRange!InputRange)
{
    alias R = InputRange;
    alias predFun = unaryFun!pred;
    static if (isNarrowString!R)
    {
        ...
    }
    else static if (!isInfinite!R && hasSlicing!R && is(typeof(haystack[cast(size_t)0 .. $])))
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        foreach (ref e; haystack) // <-- needs a ref
        {
            if (predFun(e))
                return haystack[i .. $];
            ++i;
        }
        return haystack[$ .. $];
    }
    else
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

This most likely happens because I have provided an implementation of `opApply` that does not provide a `ref` argument (neither does the class provide a `ref` return type to any other member function).

```
int opApply(int delegate(E) f) {...}
int opApply(int delegate(size_t,E) f) {...}
```

I could change that, but what really bothers me is that right now the range class complies to the preconditions of the function, and `foreach` iteration should still work with them anyway. Quoting from the documentation:

> Iteration over struct and class objects can be done with ranges. For `foreach`, this means the following properties and methods must be defined:
>
> Properties:
>
> - `.empty`    returns true if no more elements
> - `.front`    return the leftmost element of the range
>
> Methods:
>
> - `.popFront()`   move the left edge of the range right by one

All these were provided (otherwise it wouldn't be a random access range), so it should use them. Instead, it might be looking for the alternate iteration method described next:

> If the aggregate expression is a struct or class object, **and the range properties do not exist**, then the foreach is defined by the special `opApply` member function and the foreach_reverse behavior is defined by the special `opApplyReverse` member function. These functions have the type:
>
> `int opApply(int delegate(ref Type [, ...]) dg);`

Which to my interpretation, shouldn't have been looked for.

Also quoting `std.algorithm.all`, which does not seem to demand iteration for references either:

> `bool all(Range)(Range range) if (isInputRange!Range && is(typeof(unaryFun!pred(range.front))));`
>
> Returns true if and only if
>   all values v found in the input range range satisfy the predicate
>   pred. Performs (at most) Ο(range.length) evaluations of pred.

So is this a bug in the Phobos library, and `std.algorithm.find` should iterate by value in the first place? Or is there something that I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't even make sense to declare `opApply` on an object that's supposed to be a range, because if it's a range, then the range-based functions will be used for `foreach`, not `opApply`. Certainly, if `opApply` is being called on a range type instead of `front`, `popFront`, and `empty`, then that's a compiler bug. From the sounds of it, the compiler is incorrectly selecting `opApply` because the `opApply` uses `ref`, whereas `front` does not. However, the `front` works just fine without `ref` with `foreach` that uses `ref` as long as `opApply` is not declared. So, the `ref` isn't a problem so much as the fact that the compiler incorrectly uses `opApply` when it sees that `opApply` has `ref` and `front` doesn't.

So, the compiler needs to be fixed, but this probably never got caught before, because it makes no sense to declare `opApply` on a range type like you're doing. So, I'd argue that your code needs to be changed to not declare `opApply` on a range type. Then you wouldn't even hit this particular bug.

That being said, the code in question in Phobos *is* buggy for ranges which are reference types (like classes), because it fails to call `save` on `haystack` when it iterates over it. The result of that is that the original range gets mutated to refer to the spot that's being searched for, whereas what's returned points to as far past the correct spot as the element was from the front of the haystack. So, even if you stop declaring `opApply` and/or the compiler bug gets fixed, std.algorithm.find will need to be fixed for your code to start working if you're using a reference type for the range.

**EDIT:**

Okay. That's not quite right. I have been corrected in discussing it with some compiler devs. It used to be that the range functions were favored over `opApply`, and that's what the spec says, but at some point, it was changed so that `opApply` was favored over the range functions so that a range type could iterate using `opApply` with `foreach` if that was more efficient for it (though that obviously introduces the risk of the range functions and `opApply` not having the same behavior, which could result in some really nasty bugs). So, the spec does not match the current behavior of the compiler, and it *should* work for you to declare `opApply` on a range type (though I'd still advise against it unless you're getting a definite performance gain out of it).

That being said, the fact that you're getting an error here is still a compiler bug. Since your `opApply` doesn't use `ref`, it won't work with a `ref` loop variable, whereas the range functions would, so the compiler should be calling the range functions in that case, and clearly it's not. Either way, this wasn't caught before, because almost no one uses `opApply` on ranges, since the only reason to do it is if there's a performance gain in doing so, and I'm sure that the fact that the spec still says that the range functions are preferred over`opApply` makes it so that even fewer people have tried it than might otherwise be the case.

Comment: Indeed, that nailed it. It also seems that the D community could use a few more clueless programmers for finding flaws like these. ;)